# z-index between two absolutely positioned columns?

Tags: html, css, positioning, z-index

I have a two-column layout with two 'absolute' positioned divs.

```
    #left {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    #right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0
        z-index: 0;
    }
```

In each column I have images and would like them to be able to overlap one another in differing configurations with z-index. Using wordpress, #left is populated with posts from one category then subsequently, #right is populated.

**Is it possible for an image from *#left* to be positioned above an image in *#right* but not all? In essence - can the z-indexes between two separate divs be relative to one another?**

I have assigned z-index for images in *#left* higher than that of *#right*, but images in *#right* are always on top. I assume it is something to do with the fact that #left appears first in the code?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's an option for the divs to be `position:relative` then something like this could work

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ZRCke/

HTML:

```
<div id="left">
    <img id="l1" src="http://placehold.it/300x200/f00" />
    <img id="l2" src="http://placehold.it/80x150/f00" />
    <img id="l3" src="http://placehold.it/150x100/f00" />
</div>
<div id="right">
    <img id="r1" src="http://placehold.it/250/00f" />
    <img id="r2" src="http://placehold.it/250x150/00f" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#left {position: relative;width:50%;}
#right {position: relative;margin-left:50%;width:50%;}
div img {position: absolute;}

#l1 {top: 50px;right: -50px;z-index:10}
#l2 {top: 300px;right: -10px;z-index:30}
#l3 {top: 500px;right: 20px;z-index:50}

#r1 {top:100px;left:-20px;z-index:20}
#r2 {top:400px;left:-30px;z-index:40}
```

if not I'd have to go with @SnakeFaust's answer

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something essentially like this. The issue was that since the columns were being populated dynamically via wordpress, it wasn't possible to know what top position to assign. I ended up using php to retrieve the image height from wordpress and calculate the appropriate top height for each image automatically. Works great now, thank you for the answer! (And I've never seen jsfiddle before, that's fantastic)

Answer (score 3):

No.

Once you put position:absolute on those containers, each establishes its own "stacking context" and elements within will only be z-positioned relative to each other. There's a good explanation of stacking contexts at [TimKadlec.com -- Detailed Look at Stacking in CSS](http://timkadlec.com/2008/01/detailed-look-at-stacking-in-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: why don't you use a div for every image? I mean, one div per image...